# Кривые идентификаторы в jsf

Tags: java, jsf

Ребята доброе время суток. JSF генерирует свои айдишники поверх моих... Есть ли какая нибудь возможность этого избежать?

Comment: Опишите проблему подробней. Дополните вопрос фрагментом проблемного кода.

Comment: Проблемного кода нету... Есть jsf который автоматом генерирует в xhtml свои id поверх моих ранее установленных.... Мне просто интересно возможно ли как-то отучить его от замены моих id на сгенерированные автоматом... Вот как-то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы избежать проблем при использовании идентификторов, требуется понять, как они работают. Предположим для примера, что у вас есть редактируемый `dataTable`:

```
<h:form id="f1">
  <h:dataTable id="d1" value="#{tableBean.rows}" var="row">
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{row.name}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
      <h:inputText id="x1" value="#{row.quantity}" />
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
  <h:commandButton value="save" action="#{tableBean.save}" />
</h:form>
```

Мы указали `id` только один раз, но развернётся этот код в таблицу содержащую множество строк, в каждой из которых будет поле ввода, которое должно иметь уникальный идентификатор:

```
<table id="f1:d1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>beans</td>
   <td><input id="f1:d1:0:x1" type="text" name="f1:d1:0:x1" value="0" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>carrots</td>
   <td><input id="f1:d1:1:x1" type="text" name="f1:d1:1:x1" value="0" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>corns</td>
   <td><input id="f1:d1:2:x1" type="text" name="f1:d1:2:x1" value="0" /></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Прежде всего важно понять, что есть идентификтор компонента - это то, что вы задаёте в атрибуте `id`, и есть клиентский идентификтор - то, что появится в результирующей xhtml-разметке. Если не указать идентификатор компонента, метод [UIComponent.getId()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getId--) сгенерирует случайный, типа *j_id_jsp_115874224_691*. Клиентский идентификтор генерируется методом [UIComponent.getClientId(FacesContext context)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-), в описании которого описан принцип его работы:

> Find the closest ancestor to this component in the view hierarchy that
>   implements NamingContainer. Call getContainerClientId() on it and save
>   the result as the parentId local variable. Call getId() on this
>   component and save the result as the myId local variable. If parentId
>   is non-null, let myId equal parentId +
>   UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(javax.faces.context.FacesContext) +
>   myId.

То есть метод находит ближайшего родителя, реализующего интерфейс [NamingContainer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html), получает его имя и объединяет с именем компонента с помощью разделителя, полученного вызовом `UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)`. По умолчанию разделитель - это знак двоеточия `:`.

Проще говоря, чтобы получить "управляемые" клиентские идентификторы, необходимо явно задать идентификторы родительских контейнеров - форм, таблиц и т.п., а потом обращаться к нужному элементу по полному пути, включающему родительские идентификторы, разделённые двоеточиями.

Comment: Мне до Вашего уровня пару жизней, низкий Вам поклон.